# Как сделать чтобы голосовой канал создавался на определённой позиции discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord.py, discord-api

[image: скиншот]

Мне надо сделать так чтобы канал создавался не в самом низу а после канала создать (на четвёртой позиции)
Я знаю что так можно было сделать с текстовыми каналами но не знаю как это сделать с голосовыми
код:

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if after.channel.id == 778594516969586720:
        for guild in bot.guilds:
            maincategory = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, id=778594516856733696)
            channel2 = await guild.create_voice_channel(name=f'PreName {member.display_name}', category = maincategory)
            await channel2.set_permissions(member, connect=True, mute_members=True, move_members=True)
```

Документация: [Клик!)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Точно так же, как и с текстовыми, функция создания голосового канала поддерживает все те же аргументы, что и функция создания голосового:

```py
reference = guild.get_channel(398509067385535676) # берем какой-нибудь канал за "основу"
await guild.create_voice_channel(
    "test", 
    position=reference.position+1, # создаём канал под "основой"
    category=reference.category, # в категории канала-"основы"
    reason="ABC", # С причиной "ABC" (отображается в Audit Log)
)
```